# await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I'm trying to connect to the google client API, but it's saying await is only valid in async functions regarding the **const client**. But there is an await and async?

```
const express = require("express");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
require("dotenv").config();

let testENV = JSON.parse(process.env.GOOGLE_ENV);

const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "testENV",
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
  });
});

const client = await auth.getClient();

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Running on 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only use **await**, inside the async function. Here you have used the await but that is not inside the async function.

Here you can use then-catch, instead of the await

```
const express = require("express");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
require("dotenv").config();

let testENV = JSON.parse(process.env.GOOGLE_ENV);

const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "testENV",
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
  });
});

const client = auth.getClient()
.then((client) => {
  console.log(client)
  app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Running on 3000");
});
})
.catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
```

```
const express = require("express");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
require("dotenv").config();

let testENV = JSON.parse(process.env.GOOGLE_ENV);

const app = express();

async function start() {
  app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "testENV",
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
  });
});

const client = await auth.getClient();

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Running on 3000");
});
}

start()
```